# Can I ask non-development and how to question here?

Tags: discussion

I have non-developer questions in the following area:

- WordPress security
- WordPress Maintenance
- WordPress How to

I wonder if this forum is the right place to ask.

If not, where should I post questions related to above topic?

Comment: Please note that this site is a _Q/A Site_ that builds knowledge and **not** a forum. The [faq] and "on topic section" in the [help/on-topic] will lead you to other sites about specific, non-WP areas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topics like this are *marginally* on topic. In our scope we *do* have "Development and management best practices" as allowed.

But historically we are focused on development and what exactly is “management” to be on topic is much less refined.

I would *roughly* draw a line like this: if you are a person *in charge* of the WordPress installation and have questions about operation of it as a site I would say that is on topic.

If you are *a user* in WordPress installation and have question about operating WordPress features in general (“how do I write a post?”) that is probably not a fit here.